# Multiply all array ellements

Tags: arrays, matlab, permutation

I tried to multiply elements of an array using all possible combinations. For example: `A = [2,3,5]` -> `2*3,3*5,5*2`. How can this be done in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4):

[**`nchoosek`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) with [**`prod`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html) is exactly what you're looking for.

```
C = nchoosek(A,2);    %Finding the combinations taken two at a time
Req = prod(C,2)       %Multipliying the combinations (columns)

%Output:
% Req =

%     6
%    10
%    15
```

---

or `Req=prod(nchoosek(A,2),2);` as a one-liner.

Comment: `Req = prod(C,2)` can be used

Comment: Thanks @rahnema1 , this now is more general for the case when more than 2 elements are to be used at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [2,3,5];
storage(numel(A),numel(A))=0; % or storage = zeros(numel(A)), whichever you prefer
for ii = 1:numel(A)-1
    storage(1:numel(A)-ii,ii) = A(ii)*A(ii+1:end); % Multiplication
end

storage = storage(:); % Get a single vector
storage = storage(storage~=0); % remove zeros
```

You can use a loop for the multiplication, i.e. first multiply all elements after the first one with the first, then all elements after the second with the second etc.

Comment: Ok but there is no function for this in Matlab, since you should avoid loops?

Comment: @gamma this program is comprised of MATLAB functions... and avoiding loops is not the first thing to think of, as premature optimisation is bad. Also since R2016a loops have had their speed significantly improved, so you'd need to time to see whether an alternative method is faster.